# getting facebook session key on ios without calling authorize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I m using official facebook sdk on iOS.

I need to make a opengraph call to "me" in order to get the user first name

the problem I m facing : I didn't find a way to request "me" without calling authorize

```
 [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

it works , but the user is redirected to safari and back to the app each time I need his first_name and get the message "you already authorized app bla bla bla"

Is there a way to get a valid session key without calling "authorize" ? If I dont do that i get an error while fetching "me"

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```